# Any example of arranged marriage of post-pubscent girl?

Tags: marriage

In [some scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22612/23709) it is written that a girl should be married before puberty (sex should be after puberty , just kanyadaan before puberty)
.There is even a ritual where girl once become adult goes to the house of groom.

After the girl hit puberty , she can still be married , but not in arranged marriage , but in other ways - Swaymvara , [Gandharva Vivah etc](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20479/23709) (Savitri's parents left her once she become adult and was told to find husband for herself )
All arranged marriage that I know in hindu scriptures happened when girl was pre-pubscent.
(Sita was married at 6)

Technically also , arranged marriage of post-pubscent girl is not possible due to multiple reasons -

1. In arranged marriage Kanya-Daan is performed . And [Kanya is a girl](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20479/23709) who is pre-pubscent . After puberty hits , the girl becomes Rajashwala.
2. In arranged marriage , technically the consent of the girl is not required , as the ritual is "Kanya-daan". And an adult girl have agency as women too are accountable for their actions. So, non-consensual things can't be done to a woman.

**I want to know if there are any exmaples of Kanya-Daan of post-pubscent girls in hindu scripture.**