# What was the age of Gandhari at the time of marriage?

Tags: mahabharata

What was the age of Gandhari at the time of marriage ? Is her age at the time of marriage mentioned ?

Comment: In the Mahabharata, the age of Gandhari at the time of her marriage to King Dhritarashtra is not explicitly mentioned. However, it is believed that she was around the same age as Dhritarashtra, who was born blind

Comment: @AmitMittal How ? Give reference where it can be inferred what you said.

Comment: The Mahabharata Adi Parva, Section 114, provides an account of the birth of Dhritarashtra and Pandu. In this section, it is mentioned that Ambika was frightened upon seeing Sage Vyasa's appearance, which resulted in the birth of Dhritarashtra being blind. The section does not mention the age of Gandhari at the time of her marriage, but it is generally believed that she was of a similar age as Dhritarashtra.

Comment: @AmitMittal I am asking on what basis you are saying that Gandhari was of same age as Dritrastra ? If yes (only if the previous thing is confirmed ) , what was the age od dritrastras at marriage . I am asking this as it was arranged marriage and I want to know if [post-pubscent girl can be arranged married or not.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54799/any-example-of-arranged-marriage-of-post-pubscent-girl)

Comment: There is no specific scriptural reference or historical evidence that mentions the exact age of Gandhari at the time of her marriage to King Dhritarashtra. The information regarding the age of Gandhari at the time of her marriage is mostly based on the interpretation and analysis of the Mahabharata text by various scholars and writers over time.

Comment: @AmitMittal Umm Section CXIV doesn't mention their births at all...